# User accounts on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, users

I'm new to Ubuntu server and I'm having a little trouble with a project.

I need to add a user account, add a comment, create and set the home directory, add primary group to user, and set the password for the user.

I have no problem doing these individually, but for my project I need to use a single command to create the user with the properties listed.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are the home dir, grp name to the same as the username or are they to be different?

Comment: Same as username (isatssh) home directory should be /home/isatssh, group name should be isatssh

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script) and [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also have a look at `man useradd`.

`sudo useradd -c 'this is Bob' -d /home/bob -g users -m -p 'aXjeklexjklrewj' bob`

(NB: you have to give here the encrypted password)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "a comment" you are referring to an entry in the GECOS field, you can do this using the `newusers` command. From `man newusers`:

```
NAME
       newusers - update and create new users in batch

SYNOPSIS
       newusers [options] [file]

DESCRIPTION
       The newusers command reads a file (or the standard input by default)
       and uses this information to update a set of existing users or to
       create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard
       password file (see passwd(5)) with the exceptions explained below:

       pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell
```

Ex.

```
$ sudo newusers << EOF
bob:12$dta%:::comment:/home/bob:/bin/bash
EOF
[sudo] password for steeldriver:
```

Checking

```
$ getent passwd bob
bob:x:1002:1002:comment:/home/bob:/bin/bash
$ ls -ld /home/bob
drwxr-xr-x 2 bob bob 4096 Nov 29 20:25 /home/bob
```